# Python Pandas equivalent to Excel VBA TxtConvert

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I'd like to consolidate all values from a data frame column (containing roughly 100-500 records on average to single string text, so that I can pass it through the where clause of a query that pulls from a larger table on our SQL Server containing over 6 million records of data.

In the example code I provided below, I would like to queryp2 to show as "'4','5','6'"

I'm not sure if this is possible and if I missed that this question has been answered before, I will delete the question. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#df example
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
queryp1 = "SELECT * FROM PROD_DB.VERY_LARGE_TABLE WHERE B IN ("
queryp2 = "PLEASE HELP"
queryp3 = ");"
query_final = queryp1+queryp2+queryp3
#Intended results for queryp2 would actually be "'4','5','6'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
str([str(x) for x in df['B']]).strip('[]')
```

which returns:

```
"'4', '5', '6'"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
queryp2 = ' '.join(df['B'].values.astype(str))
```

Comment: Thanks! I chose another suggestion, but I appreciate this alternative method.